# Replacing hot water shower faucet cartridge

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

My hot water in the shower just spontaneously started running. The home is 50 years old and don't know when the existing faucets were installed. I figure that the cartridge needs to be replaced so I popped off the handle. Here is a picture

[image]

The problem is that the female brass end is encased in some hardened material inside the wall. Do I need to take a chisel to this or hammer drill with a 1/4" bit to knock some of the material away in order to looseen or should I be able to pry the longer piece that is attached to the O-ring out? I can't seem to get either to budge.

Comment: The nut in the wall is compressing o-ring around the handle. Use some WD-40 to loosen it

Answer (score 2):

To update: I just bought a "10I-7H/C Hot and Cold Stem for Price Pfister Faucets" from Home Depot and used a large cresecent wrench to muscle the entire thing out of its socket by gripping onto the large exposed nut (not the skinny stem). It was screwed in so no damage done to the wall. Then just slipped the replacement in and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for update and the solution, others might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful a few times with this type of problem. The solution may take a week. The deposit appears to be calcium with some corrosion. Given its location you cannot get at it easily but if you soak a cloth with a mild  acid, vinegar recommended, and pack it around the valve. Every few hours the cloth will dry out so soak it again with vinegar and put it back. This might take several days but for me it worked.